# PHP: How to insert some code into a field

Tags: php, drupal, field

I would like to know how can I manually insert some php code inside a cck node (in Drupal).
The thing is that I have this stuff:

```
$output .= '<br>';
$mor = _pitch_detalle($cid, $previamente, $luego);
if (sizeof($mor) > 0){
  $output .= theme('pitch', $mor);
}
return $output;
```

This stuff shows some information that changes from day to day, and each time the users view the page, the information changes.
I want the user to see an unmodified version of that code, the same information that existed when the user created the page.

As the user **cannot edit** the page, I think that ist´s pretty safe to say that **if I enter that code inside a field, it will remain unchanged. Is that assumption correct?**
How could I do that?

Thanks for your help!!!
Rosamunda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using drupal core revision functionality?

With the functions `node_revision_list` and `node_load` you could load the "first" revision (version) of the node.

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_load/7
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_revision_list/7

Answer (score 1):

I would think you could do this in a custom template for the page too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I´ve tried, but as that is dynamic generated content, it shows the content as it is when the viewer acceses the site. I would like it to show the content as it was when the node was published.